# Creating Questions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been following this guide to make a Ruby on Rails web app:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

It is supposed to be a quiz where people answer questions.

I have made :questions a resource. However, the guide mentions a page on its website to be able to create and delete its resource articles. Obviously this makes no sense with quiz questions as I just want to create them once and after that no more can be created or deleted. However, there is no mention of this in the guide?

Comment: I cannot fully understand your question but I will try to answer it the best way I can. If you are creating a Questions resource, i am sure you may want to add more questions or even delete one or more questions if it is wrong or for some reason you need to change it in the future. The create and delete actions are there to make a RESTful resource but if you really don't want to include delete in your resource, you can choose to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be able to create/update/destroy your questions through controller, you can exclude these restful routes with `:except`, or specify the routes you need with `:only` which is more obvious([take a look at the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)):

```
resources :questions, only: [:index, :show]
```

This will create following routes:

```
GET /questions      questions#index
GET /questions/:id  questions#show
```

To fill your database with questions, use seeds([which are described in AR migrations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)). Put your questions creation related code into `db/seeds.rb` file and run `rake db:seed` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in your routes to only `:show` the questions.

Do something like this in your routes:

`resources :questions, only: [:show]`

Answer (score 0):

So as much I understand, you want to create resources and data on your own but don't want other users to be able to create or delete a resource, right?

let's start with the basics:

> In MVC, the model/resource is the main representation of the entities.
>   The routes file indicate what routes are available at the first place
>   for each entity to which HTML requests can be sent. It also matches the route with a respective controller action. The controller
>   provides a gateway for users to interact with your application, takes
>   a request from them, take actions needed( issue SQL commands to create, show, delete from the database etc) and give a suitable response at the end.

So, suppose you want users to create a new resource on your server. First, you provide a route on which they can send a request. Then, you give them a create new resource button in your view through which they can interact. That button will use the route, match it with a controller action and send a request to that controller method. Depending on what is inside the controller action, the controller then creates the resource and redirect the user with a 302 with a notification.

Now, suppose you don't want a request to go through. What will you do?
You will firstly not create a route on which a request can be sent. You will also not create a controller action on which request can be received.

That's the use case in your scenario.

Since you don't want users to be able to send a request to the server to create the resource:

1. Don't provide the routes for them to send any such HTML request
2. Don't provide any controller which will receive such request
3. And obviously, don't provide any button in the view to take that action.

Now, the question would be: Then how will I create the resource?

You have three options:

1. Use a seed file: You can use a seed file where you add all the data you want. This tutorial and many other resources on the web can help you out. http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html
2. Use rails console: Give create commands: Question.create(:name => "hello", :description => "How you doing!"). See the link here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class
3. If you are a beginner, you need to work a little more before trying this: Create authorized users and what actions they can take. You can also create an admin dashboard and provide all actions to admin users using activeadmin gem.
   This blog explains the process: http://www.onceaday.today/subjects/1/posts/9 [3](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin)

Finally, as you do need to show all the questions: create only show route, match it with a controller action, write the method in the controller action which issues a SQL command to get all the resource from the database and give the respective show view the data it can render.

Hope it helps you out!